# How to config the DocuSign Callback function after the signature? what 's the difference between callback function and dsReturnUrl,dsPingUrl?

Tags: docusignapi

Have several questions about DocuSign API.

1 How to config the DocuSign Callback function after the signature?

2 What's the difference between callback function and dsReturnUrl, dsPingUrl?

```
private static RecipientViewRequest MakeRecipientViewRequest(string signerEmail, string signerName, string signerClientId)
    {
        // Data for this method
        // signerEmail 
        // signerName
        // dsPingUrl -- class global
        // signerClientId -- class global
        // dsReturnUrl -- class global

        RecipientViewRequest viewRequest = new RecipientViewRequest();

        // Set the url where you want the recipient to go once they are done signing
        // should typically be a callback route somewhere in your app.
        // The query parameter is included as an example of how
        // to save/recover state information during the redirect to
        // the DocuSign signing ceremony. It's usually better to use
        // the session mechanism of your web framework. Query parameters
        // can be changed/spoofed very easily.
        viewRequest.ReturnUrl = dsReturnUrl + "?state=123";

        // How has your app authenticated the user? In addition to your app's
        // authentication, you can include authenticate steps from DocuSign.
        // Eg, SMS authentication
        viewRequest.AuthenticationMethod = "none";

        // Recipient information must match embedded recipient info
        // we used to create the envelope.
        viewRequest.Email = signerEmail;
        viewRequest.UserName = signerName;
        viewRequest.ClientUserId = signerClientId;

        // DocuSign recommends that you redirect to DocuSign for the
        // Signing Ceremony. There are multiple ways to save state.
        // To maintain your application's session, use the pingUrl
        // parameter. It causes the DocuSign Signing Ceremony web page
        // (not the DocuSign server) to send pings via AJAX to your
        // app,
        viewRequest.PingFrequency = "600"; // seconds
                                           // NOTE: The pings will only be sent if the pingUrl is an https address
        viewRequest.PingUrl = dsPingUrl; // optional setting

        return viewRequest;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean to redirect back to your app when you use embedded signing.
This is the `ReturnUrl` in your code. This is where DocuSign will redirect the browser after the user of your application finished signing.

Now `pingUrl` is used to maintain state, AJAX calls would be made to your app by DocuSign to let you know the current state of your signer so that you would know if they maybe abandoned it. This is useful if you don't use an iframe but rather a new window for the signing and you want the original window to be aware of something like the user simply closing the signing window for example.

More information:

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-in-app-embedded/

Comment: Thanks for your response.  "Callback" means after all party's signature, I think DocuSign should send a request to some URL about the signature result. and where can I see the request body so that I can know how to parse the request?

Comment: you may mean DocuSign connect webhook? that's a backend feature, not a redirect on the front end. Start here - https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect/

Comment: As Inbar stated, the embedded signing redirect is where the signer's browser gets redirected when they exit the signing view.  Use this to continue the web workflow within your UI, i.e. take the signer to the appropriate next page in the UI workflow.  To manage the envelope itself, use the Connect message, which is more reliable, to act on envelope state, e.g. download completed documents, kick off asynchronous actions, etc.